# powershell msbuild Microsoft.WebApplication.targets not found

Tags: .net, powershell, msbuild

I have vs 2013, 2015 and 2017 installed.
I am building a powershell project for 2015 .NET 4.7.1 to do a very specific type of deployment.
I am executing the following commands.  $Configuration is either 'Release' or 'Debug'.

```
dotnet msbuild /t:rebuild /p:Configuration=$Configuration /p:Platform=x64
```

.....
I keep getting the following error:
 error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.4\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
That does NOT exist on disk.
Where do I get it?
It appears to be looking for .NET core, but my project is NOT .NET core.  My project is .NET standard.
I also tried using /t (tools version) but no matter what I put, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The `dotnet` CLI (".NET Core SDK") does not support building non-"SDK" project types, which is classic csproj files and classic web applications.

While some classic csproj files may work (esp. logic-only libraries), it does not work for many other project types, which expect VS-only files to be present (such as `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets`).

Use the `msbuild.exe` of the visual studio installation to build these projects. Best to launch the developer command prompt of the visual studio version you need and run (`powershell` and then) `msbuild` from there.

If you need to run this in a build script, use [vswhere](https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere) to locate `msbuild.exe` of the VS / Build Tools 2017 installation.

Comment: The question asks about specifically 'dotnet msbuild' and the MS docs suggest that "The dotnet msbuild command allows access to a fully functional MSBuild." - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-msbuild This seems contrary to your answer.

Comment: @Jono there is MSBuild and then there is build logic built on top of MSBuild that needs to be included in yor build toolset (CLI, VS Build Tools, Visual Studio, Rider, JetBrains' MSBuild distribution, ...) which varies based on supported project types